# Use wild cards with IN syntax in SQL with python

Tags: python, sql

I want to use wildcards to retrieve customers with orders values in a list of contains all or  a part possible values :

```
sql="SELECT order from `customers` WHERE UPPER(order) IN  (%s)"
in_p=', '.join(map(lambda x: '%s',orders))
sql = sql % in_p
cur.execute(sql,orders)
```

Where orders is a list of possibles values/states of an order. This query give the exact values.

Example : in the the customers table, orders may have states values "processing", "in processing" but the list of possible values only contain "processing" and i want to retrieve all the orders.

I hope i have made myself clear.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) SQL operator:

```
where = " OR ".join(["order LIKE %s"]*len(orders))
sql = "SELECT order from `customers` WHERE " + where
cur.execute(sql, ["%{}%".format(o) for o in orders])
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea - I think they may help you

```
orders=['a','b','c']
sql="SELECT order from `customers` WHERE UPPER(order) IN  (%s)"
in_p=', '.join(map(lambda x: str.format('\'{}\'',x),orders))
sql_command = sql % in_p
```

`sql_command` will be

```
SELECT order from `customers` WHERE UPPER(order) IN  ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: This is not what i'm looking, the query is already working for exact values. Thank you.